# Jquery is not working in Wordpress after adding noConflict()

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I was having problems getting jQuery to work in Wordpress and I found out that jQuery may cause issues with other plugins from Wordpress so a noConflict variable needed to be added so I added this at the beginning of my script:

```
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
```

I thought this would fix the problem but my jQuery still isn't being read. I see there is a solution to use jQuery instead of the $ but I don't want to go through all my code to change the variable.

Any solutions to this problem, especially solutions where I can still use the $?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can pass the `$` shortcut into your document ready function like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    //You can use $ in here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is all your code in one file ? If so, you can wrap it in a closure:

```
jQuery.noConflict();

(function ($) {
 // your code. can now use $.
})(jQuery);
```

Or if you are already using document ready:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
 // your code. can now use $.
});
```

[jquery.noconflict() Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)